# ASP.NET Core + StreamWriter: Why does `await using` behave differently than `using`?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am trying to write directly to `Response.Body` in an ASP.NET Core 6 controller method since this is more performant in some cases.

Why do `await using` and `using` behave differently in the following code?

```cs
[Route("api/[Controller]/[Action]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("text/plain")]
    public async Task GetPlainText()
    {
        // No `using`: it works
        // Add `using` to the following line and the response will be empty
        // Add `await using` to the following line and it will work
        var sw = new StreamWriter(Response.Body, leaveOpen: true);

        await sw.WriteAsync("Some normal text");
        await sw.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/srmagura/StreamWriterConfusion)

### Edit

Whether or not `using var sw = new StreamWriter(...)` works seems to depend on the HTTP client used. If Chrome is used, there is an error in the console and no text is displayed. If Postman is used, there is no error and the response contains "Some normal text".

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. `using var sw = new StreamWriter(Response.Body, leaveOpen: true);` works just fine. Can you please post the code which leads to empty response?

Comment: @GuruStron Yes that is the code that produces the invalid response. See my edit to the question, maybe that is why you can't reproduce the problem?

Comment: Works fine for me in both. Have you tried opening new window/reloading page in Chrome?

Comment: Can you show the code example of how you are doing the using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really should have looked at the console output from ASP.NET Core, which contained this stack trace:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream.Flush()
         at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
         at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
         at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
```

So the issue is that `StreamWriter.Dispose` synchronously flushes the underlying stream, and synchronous write operations are not allowed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I would say it is because the the stream is disposed after the method completes but before the task to write and flush the stream was actually run because all that was returned was the promise to do those things.

The reason it works without the `using` is because dispose is never called.

The reason it works with the `await using` is because the disposal of the stream is also included as part of the task.

As to why the client makes a difference it could be because it is streamed to one and executed directly to the other.